# Limit of a peculiar sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^2n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-sum

Find the limit (is exists) of $$\lim_{x\longrightarrow 0^+}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^2n^2}.$$
I tried turning it into Riemann sum, but to no avail as of yet.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{1+x^2n^2}=\frac\pi x\coth\frac\pi x$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed handle it as a Riemann sum for $\int_0^\infty(1+x^2)^{-1}\,dx=\pi/2$:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac h{1+h^2n^2}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{(n-1)h}^{nh}\Bigl(\frac1{1+x^2}-\frac1{1+n^2h^2}\Bigr)\,dx\ge0
$$
while
$$\int_h^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac h{1+h^2n^2}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{nh}^{(n+1)h}\Bigl(\frac1{1+x^2}-\frac1{1+n^2h^2}\Bigr)\,dx\le0
$$
so
$$\int_h^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^2}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac h{1+h^2n^2}\le\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
and now you can let $h\to0$.

Comment: Ok, I accepted you answer, but could you please elaborate on how do you take the integral under the sum (I get the first part, but don't know how this sum is actually a sum of integrals)?

Comment: Just use $\int_0^\infty(1+x^2)^{-1}\,dx=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^{Nh}(1+x^2)^{-1}\,dx$, then split this up as a sum of $N$ integrals, and note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N$.

Comment: I know, but you say $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac h{1+h^2n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{(n-1)h}^{nh}\frac1{1+n^2h^2}\ dx$ and I'm trying to see why.

Comment: @Jules It's really quite simple. Since the function $\frac{1}{1+n^2h^2}$ is constant with respect to $x$, you can pull it outside the integral: $\int_{(n-1)h}^{nh}\frac1{1+n^2h^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{1+n^2h^2}\int_{(n-1)h}^{nh}dx$. The value of the integral is simply $\int_{(n-1)h}^{nh}dx=nh-nh+h=h$, so $\int_{(n-1)h}^{nh}\frac1{1+n^2h^2}\,dx=\frac{h}{1+n^2h^2}. Now just sum both sides.

Comment: I finally figured it out, you're right it's not that complicated ;)

Comment: Good. Note that this is quite a common trick for estimating integrals. You'll likely see it again in different contexts.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually intepret it as a Riemann sum in the following way

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+(xn)^{2}}=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{1+(\frac{n}{m})^{2}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^{2}}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: I tried doing it that way! I can just set integration bounds like this? Shouldn't it be like $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{1+(\frac{n}{m})^{2}}$ ?

Comment: I didn't see this answer until now, while I was typing away at my own. Anyhow, my answer has more detail which should make it clear. I'll +1 this in the spirit of good sportsmanship, though.

Comment: Since this is an improper integral, I think you may need to take a little more care showing that you have the correct limit of Riemann sums. I find $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{0}^{L}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\lim_{L\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{n^2+L^2k^2}$, but I'm not completely sure how to connect this double limit to your Riemann sum.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Ah, and I posted my comment before I saw your answer and comment. It looks your answer handles the issue I was worried about. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the series itself has the closed form

$$\frac12(\pi\coth{\frac{\pi}{x}}-x)$$

Comment: @Shaktal it's the negative of that. Thanks for alerting me to the typo.

Comment: Where does it come from?

Comment: @Jules See this question for a proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680825/how-to-prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n21-frac-1-pi-coth-pi?rq=1

Comment: Another approach may be to use the product formula for the sine function – se formula (23) [on the mathworld article on the sine function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sine.html) – take the logarithm of that, then differentiate. (And then replace $x$ by $ix$.)