# The limit of $f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+yn^2}$ as $x\to \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+yn^2}, \ \ \ \ y\neq 0$$
how to show that for each $y\neq 0, g(y)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x,y)$ exists, evaluate $g(y)$.
Then prove the convergence above if uniformly for $y>0$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$.

For each x and y, the series converges, but I don't know how to get the sum of the series.

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: If I am not mistaken the series is Riemannsum. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1+y(\frac{n}{x})^{2}}\rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1+yt^{2}}$$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The series has a well-known closed form in terms of elementary functions that is convenient for finding the limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+yn^2}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{y}}\coth{\left(\frac{\pi x}{\sqrt{y}}\right)}-\frac{1}{2x}.$$

A proof can be found in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680825/how-to-prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n21-frac-1-pi-coth-pi?rq=1).

Comment: Yes, In this way, we can solve this problem.