# Proving $\sum_{n=1,3,5..}^{\infty }\frac{\sin^r(n\pi/3)}{n^2}=\frac{3^{0.5r-2}}{2^r}\pi^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Proving
$$\sum_{n=1,3,5..}^{\infty }\frac{\sin^r(n\pi/3)}{n^2}=\frac{3^{0.5r-2}}{2^r}\pi^2$$
if the $r$ an even integer number greater than 0

I don't have the enough experience to prove formulas like the above, so I need some helps to prove it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{(6n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(6n+5)^2}\right) =\frac{\pi^2}{9}\tag{1} $$
written in a very ugly way. To prove the last identity, notice that the LHS equals:
$$ -\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^{6n}+x^{6n+4}\right)\log x\,dx = -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+x^4}{1-x^6}\,\log x\,dx\tag{2}$$
that can be computed with many different techniques.

Comment: Is your answer for special case or general?

Comment: @Reery: it applies just here since $\sin((2m+1)\pi/3)$ behaves like $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0,-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0,-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\ldots$ but line $(2)$ provides a general technique for writing such sums into an "integral format".

Comment: Like you said, these can be evaluated with many different techniques. One of them is the $\pi\cot(\pi z)$ multiplier technique which is well known and of which there is an example at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112161/).