# Sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(9n-1)(9n+1)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the value of

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(9n-1)(9n+1)}$$
I have tried to substitute the value of $n$ from $1$ but it is not telescoping series.

Comment: Try decomposing it to partial fraction and see if it is telescoping

Comment: Just checked, it isn't telescoping like you said. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: This [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112161/) may prove useful reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** Recall the following [series representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7#E6) for the digamma function
$$\begin{equation} 
\psi(x+1) = -\gamma - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n+x} -\frac{1}{n}  
\right), \quad \Re x >-1, \tag1
\end{equation}
$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Then by partial fraction decomposition we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(9n-1)(9n+1)} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{9n-1}-\frac{1}{9n+1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{18}\left(\frac{1}{n-1/9}-\frac{1}{n+1/9}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{18}\left[\left(\frac{1}{n-1/9}-\frac1n\right)-\left(\frac{1}{n+1/9}-\frac1n\right)\right]
\end{align}
$$ then summing from $n=1$ to $+\infty$, using $(1)$, we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(9n-1)(9n+1)} =\frac{1}{18}\left(\psi\left(\frac{10}{9}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)\right)
$$ equivalently

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(9n-1)(9n+1)} =\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{18}\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{9}\right)
> $$

where we have used [Gauss' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss.27s_digamma_theorem) for the digamma function. A numerical approximation for this series is given by $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(9n-1)(9n+1)} \approx \color{blue}{0.02047472906319532...}$$

Answer (score 2):

In general, for natural values of *a* and *b* we have $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{H_a-H_b}{a-b}$ , which

can easily be proven by decomposing the summand into partial fractions, and noticing that

the series [telescopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). However, in this case, *a* and *b* are not integers, but rather $\pm~\dfrac19$ , so the

series does not telescope. However, that is ultimately of no consequence, since, three centuries

ago, the great [Leonhard Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler) has found a way of [generalizing harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) to non–

natural arguments, so the same formula applies ! Of course, the integrals are messy, requiring

a substitution of the form $t=\sqrt[\Large^9]x$ , followed by [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). You will then

encounter difficulty evaluating $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{2~t^4+t^3+t+2}{1+t^3+t^6}dt$ , where you'll have to very graciously

tip-toe around the three cube roots of each of the two complex cube roots of unity. But, with

patience, and with the help of [complex logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) and [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula), even this hurdle will

be overcome.

Answer (score 1):

We can exploit the Weierstrass product for the sine function. Since:

$$\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z} = \prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{z^n}{n^2}\right)\tag{1}$$

by considering the logarithmic derivatives of $(1)$ it follows that:

$$ -\frac{1}{z}+\pi\cot(\pi z) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2z}{z^2-n^2}\tag{2}$$
and we just need to plug in $z=\frac{1}{9}$ to get:

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{81n^2-1}= \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{18}\,\cot\frac{\pi}{9}}.\tag{3}$$

$\cot\frac{\pi}{9}$ is an algebraic number of degree six over $\mathbb{Q}$:

$$\cot\frac{\pi}{9}=\sqrt{3+\frac{8}{\sqrt{3}}\,\cos\frac{\pi}{18}}.\tag{4} $$
By expanding the terms of the LHS of $(3)$ as geometric series we also have:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{81n^2-1}=\frac{\zeta(2)}{3^4}+\frac{\zeta(4)}{3^8}+\ldots = \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\zeta(2m)}{3^{4m}}.\tag{5}$$