# Proving $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(48n+1)(48n+47)}=\frac{\pi}{2208}(\cot(\frac{\pi}{24})+\sec(\frac{11\pi}{24}))$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Proving

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(48n+1)(48n+47)}=\frac{\pi}{2208}(\cot(\frac{\pi}{24})+\sec(\frac{11\pi}{24}))$$

When I used the WolframAlpha, I got the the following result:

[image]

I could get the alternative form of result which is above, but I m not sure if the closed-form is corrected ? 
Any help

Comment: Use FullSimplify to see if it reduces down.

Comment: Could you not split it into partial fractions and find a sum in terms of n using a method of differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is extremely similar to [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182924/how-to-show-sum-n-0-infty-frac124n524n19-frac-pi-336-sqr).
We have:
$$S=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(48n+1)(48n+47)}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(48n+24)^2-23^2}=\frac{\pi}{4\cdot 23\cdot 24}\tan\frac{23 \pi}{48},$$
hence

> $$ S = \frac{\pi}{2208}\cot\frac{\pi}{48} $$

and since $\cot\frac{\pi}{6}=\sqrt{3}$ while $\cot\frac{x}{2}=\cot x+\sqrt{1+\cot^2 x}$, we have:
$$\cot\frac{\pi}{12}=2+\sqrt{3},\quad \cot\frac{\pi}{24}=2+\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$$
and:

> $$\cot\frac{\pi}{48}=2+\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}+2\sqrt{4+2 \sqrt{3}+2 \sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt{3 \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)}}$$

is an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree $8$ and minimal polynomial
$1+16 x+4 x^2-112 x^3+6 x^4+112 x^5+4 x^6-16 x^7+x^8$.

Comment: I want to ask , why the Wolfram can not give a form similar to this?

Comment: @Easy: it can for sure with a suitable combination of *Fullsimplify* and *Refine*, but this is not difficult to compute also by hand.

Comment: thanks, Jack D'Aurizio( your answer very nice)

Answer (score 2):

You may recall the following [series representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7#E6) for the digamma function
$$\begin{equation} 
\psi(x+1) = -\gamma - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n+x} -\frac{1}{n}  
\right), \quad \Re x >-1, \tag1
\end{equation}
$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Then by partial fraction decomposition we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(48n+1)(48n+47)} &= \frac{1}{46}\left(\frac{1}{48n+1}-\frac{1}{48n+47}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2208}\left(\frac{1}{n+1/48}-\frac{1}{n+47/48}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2208}\left[\left(\frac{1}{n+1/48}-\frac1n\right)-\left(\frac{1}{n+47/48}-\frac1n\right)\right]
\end{align}
$$ then summing from $n=1$ to $+\infty$, using $(1)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(48n+1)(48n+47)} &=\frac{1}{2208}\left(\psi\left(\frac{47}{48}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{48}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2208}\left(\psi\left(1-\frac{1}{48}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{48}\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$ then recall that, from the [Euler reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) you have
$$
\psi\left(x\right)-\psi\left(1-x\right)=- \pi \cot(\pi x)
$$
leading to

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(48n+1)(48n+47)}=\frac{\pi}{2208}\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{48}\right).
> $$

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment to the "Olivier Oloa"s answer. Using [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_trigonometric_constants) and some fun with radicals we get:
$$\cot\Big(\frac{\pi}{48}\Big)=\sqrt{\frac{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}}$$