# Prove the Identity $\pi=2- \sum_{1}^{∞} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2-\frac{1}{4}} $

Tags: summation, fourier-series, riemann-sum

By considering the fact that $f(\pi/2)=1$, prove the identity

$\pi=2- \sum_{1}^{∞} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2-\frac{1}{4}} $

This question was is a subsection in a chapter on Fourier series, can I use my understanding of Fourier series to prove the identity, or is there an easier way of making the proof?

**EDIT** Another part of this question asked to find the Fourier series of the periodic function $f(x)$ defined by $f(x)= |sin(x)|$, this is the function they are probably referring to in the proof.

Comment: What function is $f$?

Comment: Presumably you need to take whatever $f$ is, find its series expansion, plug in $\pi/2$, and then maybe do some algebra.

Comment: $f(x)=|sin(x)|$ @DanielFischer

Comment: I suppose   using complex variables $$h(z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}\frac{1}{z^2-1/4}$$ should work well here. This is not the same as the function referenced by the OP.

Comment: The function which is to be used is $f(x)=|sin(x)|$, when I calculate its Fourier series expansion, what would be the next step in equating it to a summation involving an $m$ constant? @Ian

Comment: How would I use this function to prove the identity? @MarkoRiedel

Comment: So you have the Fourier series, and probably know that it converges pointwise to $f$, Thus plug $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ into $$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n \cos (nx).$$

Comment: The comment above refers to this [technique (MSE link)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112161/) which admittedly does not use Fourier series. (Compute all residues at the poles of $h(z)$ and show that the integral along the contour vanishes in the limit.)

Comment: You can prove this only using the Gregory-Leibniz series for $\frac\pi4$. (I'm referring to $\frac\pi4=1-\frac13+\frac15-\dotsb$.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw: very true. It is enough to rearrange a little the RHS of the first line of my proof.

Answer (score 12):

Fourier series are not really needed to prove the identity:
$$\begin{align*}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^m}{4m^2-1}&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m\geq 1}(-1)^m\left(\frac{1}{2m-1}-\frac{1}{2m+1}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m\geq 1}(-1)^m\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^{2m-2}-x^{2m}\right)\,dx\\&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\,dx\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-2\arctan 1\right)\\&=\color{red}{\frac{2-\pi}{4}}.\end{align*}$$

Comment: Very nice. Much simpler than mine.

Comment: I just posted a solution for a tedious integral and received a comment that a wise young man once said, and I'm paraphrasing here, that there is more than 1 way to skin a series.

Comment: Can anyone explain how to get from the second line to the third?

Comment: @hans__ You mean, how he got rid of the $\sum$? Switch $\sum$ and $\int$, and use the geometric series.

Comment: @columbus8myhw how is the switch possible? And we have $0\leq x\leq 1$ instead of $0\leq x <1$, no? I am mindful of the gap in my knowledge of analysis.

Comment: @hans__: a single point does not matter for integration purposes. $x^{2m-2}-x^{2m}$ is a non-negative and bounded function on $(0,1)$ having integral $O\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$, so we are more than allowed to switch the series and the integral (we have absolute convergence).

Comment: You could have separated the series, made a substitution, and recombined, rather than messing with integrals, I believe. It would lead you straight to the Gregory-Leibniz formula.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: I do not think my approach is "messy" but you are right, that is an even shorter way.

Comment: "Messing," not "messy." I didn't mean to imply anything.

Answer (score 3):

I'll play around and see what happens.

We want
$\pi=2- \sum_{1}^{∞} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2-\frac{1}{4}}
$

$\begin{array}\\
S
&=\sum_{m=1}^{∞} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2-\frac{1}{4}}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{∞} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2}\frac1{1-\frac{1}{4m^2}}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{∞} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4m^{2})^j}\\
&=4\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^m\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4m^{2})^{j+1}}\\
&=4\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^m\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4m^{2})^{j}}\\
&=4\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^m\frac{1}{(4m^{2})^{j}}\\
&=4\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac1{4^j}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^m\frac{1}{(m^{2})^{j}}\\
&=4\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac1{4^j}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^m\frac{1}{m^{2j}}\\
&=-4\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac1{4^j}\zeta(2j)(1-2^{1-2j})\\
&=-4\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac1{4^j}\zeta(2j)+8\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac1{4^{2j}}\zeta(2j))\\
\end{array}
$

According to
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function,
$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2j)-1}{4^j}
=\frac16
$
and
$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2j)-1}{16^j}
=\frac{13}{30}-\frac{\pi}{8}
$.
Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2j)}{4^j}
&=\frac16+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^j}\\
&=\frac16+\frac{1/4}{1-1/4}\\
&=\frac16+\frac13\\
&=\frac12\\
\end{array}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2j)}{16^j}
&=\frac{13}{30}-\frac{\pi}{8}+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{16^j}\\
&=\frac{13}{30}-\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{1/16}{1-1/16}\\
&=\frac{13}{30}-\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{1}{15}\\
&=\frac12-\frac{\pi}{8}\\
\end{array}
$.

Putting this together,

$\begin{array}\\
S
&=-4\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac1{4^j}\zeta(2j)+8\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac1{4^{2j}}\zeta(2j)\\
&=-4(\frac12)+8(\frac12-\frac{\pi}{8})\\
&=-2+4-\pi\\
&=2-\pi\\
\end{array}
$.

Whew!

Comment: Even though someone posted a simpler solution, +1 for typing all of that out

Comment: Funny, but this proof is probably circular.

Comment: @user109899: I do not think so. With marty's conversion it is enough to exploit $$\forall x\in(-1,1),\qquad \sum_{n\geq 1}\zeta(2n)\,x^{2n}=\frac{1-\pi x\cot(\pi x)}{2}.$$