# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4(-1)^n}{1-4n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I recently found a series representation for 1 from the calculation of a Fourier series:
$$1 = \frac{2}{\pi} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4(-1)^n}{\pi(1-4n^2)}$$
From this, I can easily find that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4(-1)^n}{1-4n^2} = \pi - 2,$$
but what other methods are there to evaluate the sum? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: It looks like the denominator can be split by factoring and using partial fractions.  Trying different values for $n$ I can see a definite pattern.

Comment: You've written two different equations above by the way.

Comment: @ElliotG you're right, sorry! Fixed.

Comment: Using the method at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112161/) introduce $$f(z) = \frac{4\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}\frac{1}{1-4z^2}$$ and observe that $$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\pm 1/2} f(z) = -\pi \quad\text{and}\quad \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} f(z) = 4.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{4}{1-4 n^2} = \frac{2}{1-2 n} + \frac{2}{1+2 n}$$

Thus,
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4 (-1)^n}{1-4 n^2} &= 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2 n-1}+2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2 n+1} \\ &= 2 \frac{\pi}{4} + 2 \left (\frac{\pi}{4}-1 \right ) \\ &= \pi-2 \end{align}$$

Comment: It always comes back to arctan...

Comment: How do you get from the right side of the second line to the third line? Is that related to the arc tangent, as @ElliotG mentioned?

Comment: @feralin: yes, it follows from a Maclurin expansion of the arctangent.  It is also known as the Gregory series for Pi and has been in existence since the 18th century.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I learn something every day...

Comment: Interesting is the fact that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4(-1)^n}{1-4n^2}x^n=\frac{2 (x+1) \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}-2$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici how do you prove that?

Comment: @GohP.iHan. No idea ! I just tried with a CAS and got this funny result.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici well it's true for $ x=1 $ by applying Abel's Theorem. Do you mind if I ask this problem in MSE?

Comment: @GohP.iHan. Why do you want me to mind ? Just go ahead. By the way, **Merry Xmas**. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici [Posted](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588672/)!!! MERRY XMAS!!!!