# Mittag-Leffler Theorem Exercise - Find Sum of Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

The exercise asks to find the closed form of $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z+n)^2+a^2}$$where $a$ is a complex number.

I know that $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z+n)^2}$, but don't how to develop this fact. Is this some kind of a shift of this series?

Thank you!

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2152074/42969