# About the proof of $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)=-\pi\sum\limits_{k=1}^m\text{res} [f(z)\cot(\pi z)]_{z=a_k}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, meromorphic-functions

> Let $f(z)$ be a meromorphic function with a finite number of poles $a_1,\dots,a_m$, where $a_i\not\in\mathbb Z\cup\{0\}$.
>
> Prove that if there exists a sequence of contours $\{C_n\}$ that goes to the point infinity  and is such that $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{C_n}f(z)\cot (\pi z)dz=0,$$ then $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)=-\pi\sum_{k=1}^m\text{res} [f(z)\cot(\pi z)]_{z=a_k}$$

From Marsden book:

> [image]

[image]

What does it mean the part that says

*Taking limits on both sides...*

If you take the limits,

$\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^{N} f(n)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum\text{res} [f(z)\pi\cot(\pi z)]_{z=n}\dots (*)$

and how do you pass from  $(*)$ to $\displaystyle-\sum_{k=1}^m\text{res} [\pi f(z)\cot(\pi z)]_{z=a_k}$ ?

Could anyone explain please?

Thank you

Comment: There is an example computation at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112161/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Taking limits on both sides of the preceding displayed equation for the integral $\oint_{C_N}(\pi\cot\pi z)f(z)dz$

This means taking the limit $N\to\infty$ on both sides of 
$$
\begin{align}
\oint_{C_N}f(z)dz 
&=2\pi i\sum\text{Res $(\pi\cot\pi z)f(z)$ at $-N,\cdots,+N$} \\
&~~~~+2\pi i\sum\text{Res $(\pi\cot\pi z)f(z)$ at singularities of $f$} \\
\end{align}
$$

which is
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{N\to\infty}\oint_{C_N}f(z)dz 
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}2\pi i\sum\text{Res $(\pi\cot\pi z)f(z)$ at $-N,\cdots,+N$} \\
&~~~~+\lim_{N\to\infty}2\pi i\sum\text{Res $(\pi\cot\pi z)f(z)$ at singularities of $f$} \\
\end{align}
$$

> and using the fact that $\oint_{C_N}(\pi\cot\pi z)f(z)dz\to0$ as $N\to\infty$,

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}2\pi i\sum\text{Res $(\pi\cot\pi z)f(z)$ at $-N,\cdots,+N$} \\
&~~~~+\lim_{N\to\infty}2\pi i\sum\text{Res $(\pi\cot\pi z)f(z)$ at singularities of $f$} \qquad{(*)}\\
\end{align}
$$

---

Since for an integer $k$ $$\text{Res $(\pi\cot\pi z)f(z)$ at $k$}=f(k)$$
we can rewrite $(*)$ as
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}2\pi i\sum_{k=-N}^N f(k) \\
&~~~~+\lim_{N\to\infty}2\pi i\sum\text{Res $(\pi\cot\pi z)f(z)$ at singularities of $f$} \\
\end{align}
$$

---

Furthermore, recognizing that the second sum does not depend on $N$ for large enough $N$, we have

$$\begin{align}
0
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}2\pi i\sum_{k=-N}^N f(k) 
+2\pi i\sum\text{Res $(\pi\cot\pi z)f(z)$ at singularities of $f$} \\
0
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=-N}^N f(k) 
+\sum\text{Res $(\pi\cot\pi z)f(z)$ at singularities of $f$} \\
\end{align}
$$
$$
\color{red}{
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=-N}^N f(k)
=-\sum\text{Res $(\pi\cot\pi z)f(z)$ at singularities of $f$}}  
$$